# Input tag with initial value but changeable

Tags: jquery

I'm working on an edit implementation - how can I set a default value for an `input` but can still be changed to be saved on the database using jQuery? Is it even possible? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Initially, if I load the page for editing, there should be an initial value retrieved from the database depending on which `id` am I currently iterating. But then I have an option to change the input and should replace the old value retrieved from the database

here's the code

```
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label for="vpTitle">Button Label</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" id="vpDonateButtonLabel"
            name="volunteerProject.donateButtonLabel"
            placeholder="Enter button label" maxlength="50" value="${volunteerProject.donateButtonLabel}" required />
        </div>
```

it displays what I'm expecting when I first load the page. After I have inputted a new value, then clicking save, and open the page again, it still shows what I have written in `value`. Sorry, I am very new to JavaScript and having a really hard time learning it.

Comment: Can't you just set it's value to be the default?

`<input type="text" name="myinput" value="Enter your text..">`

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: What is this notation  ${ } ?

Comment: @DamianGreen it's for the framework Struts, it is how I call a value passed from the back end. hehehe I'm not so sure

Comment: @SunilKumar I have tried this

    `$('#vpDonateCountLabel').change(function(){
  $('#vpDonateCountLabel').val($(this).val());
    });`

is this right?

Comment: @Toby Yes, I have put a default value but I do need to have an option to change it whenever I want to

Comment: not familiar with struts, but i'd remove the value attribute from your html and bind this value in your javascript as i wrote in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just populate the value, then they can edit it

```
$('#inputId').val('default value')
```